# How to make pages jump smoothly with fakeLoader.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the [fakeLoader.js](https://github.com/joaopereirawd/fakeLoader.js/) plugin for faking a loading effect between my pages. However, it seems it refreshes the page before the effect takes place, when I switch between pages. I followed the instructions, but nothing seems to be happening.

**HTML**

```
<div id="loader">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".loader").fakeLoader({
  timeToHide:1000,
  zIndex:"999",
  spinner:"spinner2",
  bgColor:"#fff", //Hex, RGB or RGBA colors
  imagePath:"assets/img/loading.gif"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ready` method was implemented in jQuery to execute code when the DOM is fully loaded. Since it executes the given function when all DOM elements are available, you can be sure that trying to access or manipulate elements will work.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".loader").fakeLoader({
      timeToHide:1000,
      zIndex:"999",
      spinner:"spinner2",
      bgColor:"#fff", //Hex, RGB or RGBA colors
      imagePath:"assets/img/loading.gif"
    });
});
```

Would you please add your `JS`. In document ready and try it?

Comment: @ChristopherBobby would you please check console and let us know what is the error?

Comment: @ChristopherBobby http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132356/how-to-make-pages-jump-smoothly-with-fakeloader-js Would you please join this chat room? So I can batter way to solve your issue.

Comment: @ChristopherBobby have you add [jquery.min.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js) in your `<head>` tag?

Comment: it says Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function
    at r.fn.init.r.fn.load (jquery-3.0.0.min.js:4)
    at fakeLoader.js:120
    at fakeLoader.js:128

Comment: i cant join the chat, low reputation

Comment: yeah.. without jquery it won't load at all

Comment: @ChristopherBobby Would you please provide your full `HTML` code? I will batter way to check this issue.

Comment: well, it's too long and stack overflow does not permit it, but it basically 
html doc, 
head,
the loader div
body
the JS (jquery code)

Comment: @ChristopherBobby would you please create snippet http://screencast.com/t/IMTvzNGP ?